# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined (reactjs-popup.es.js:8)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack

Getting this error out of blue in our react app. We build the app through docker container, and any build which went through few days back are all fine. Recent builds are throwing this error.
We have compared the package and package-lock.json and there is no difference between the working and non working versions.

we have the below webpack configs

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
}),
```

we also have new Dotenv(), inside plugins.

Tried adding alias which didn't help.

We also have the 'process' library installed, and as previously said, everything was working fine one days earlier.

Any points on debugging this further please.

As suggested by others, process is not available for browser, but we have already configured in webpack to make it available. Have Dotenv() added in plugins, and tried general steps like adding 'process' in alias/resolve, etc,
Also compared the working and none working package files. So want some pointers